# Setting IPv4 address and domaine restrictions in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, ip, ipv4, restrictions

I have a couple of sites that I want to only allow access to specific IPs. I have added these IP addresses to IIS7 via the IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions functionality, as per the link below:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731598%28WS.10%29.aspx

I have also seen mention of using the management service (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889%28WS.10%29.aspx), although this (to me) appears to set the restrictions at too high a level?

Anyway, I have added 4 IP addresses as 'Allow' but I can still connect to the site from a different IP address.

Can anyone clarify how I can ensure that only the listed Allow addresses can actually get through? I'm new to this so please forgive me if I sound like a dumbass!

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  Also check the "Edit Feature Settings" in IIS Manager.  Change "Access for unspecified clients" from Allow to Deny.

Comment: Nice one Scott - seems to be working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!